# How to use @PathVariable to resolve parameter name in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to use @PreAuthorize annotations to secure methods in Spring REST controller, using method parameters, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/something/{myParam}")
@PreAuthorize("@security.check(#myParam)")
public String getSomething(@PathVariable("myParam") Integer myParam) {
  //...
}
```

Spring Security needs a way to discover param names in runtime. When there is no debugging symbols in the compiled class, it is necessary to add a special annotation @P or Spring Data's @Param. So, the method would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/something/{myParam}")
@PreAuthorize("@security.check(#myParam)")
public String getSomething(@PathVariable("myParam") @P("myParam) Integer myParam) {
  //...
}
```

Is it possible to somehow hint Spring Security to use @PathVariable instead and avoid additional annotations like @P?

According to [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#method-security-expressions) reading parameter names from annotations is done by `AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer` *which can be customized to support the value attribute of any specified annotation.* However, I could not find any information on **how** to customize it.

BTW, I'm using Java 7 and Spring Security 3.2.9.

Comment: what version of spring-core do you use?

Comment: @RomanSandarkin 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: thank you. It seems that I have found a solution )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official Spring security docs [GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#globalmethodsecurityconfiguration)

> Sometimes you may need to perform operations that are more complicated
>   than are possible with the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation
>   allow. For these instances, you can extend the
>   `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` ensuring that the
>   `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation is present on your subclass.
>   For example, if you wanted to provide a custom
>   `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, you could use the following
>   configuration:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        // ... create and return custom MethodSecurityExpressionHandler ...
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

As in the above example you can write your custom `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` or use the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and [set](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java#L197) your custom [ParameterNameDiscoverer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java#L56) extending the [DefaultSecurityParameterNameDiscoverer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/parameters/DefaultSecurityParameterNameDiscoverer.java) (or not)

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new CustomParameterNameDiscoverer());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

One more example [Spring Security Java Config Preview: Custom Method Security](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/#custom-method-security)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have used this solution in my test configuration - not with a custom parameter name discoverer, but with `AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer`, setting desired annotations to use: `new AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer(PathVariable.class.getName(), P.class.getName())`. It works.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you need to override creating of [`SecurityExpressionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler.html) in the method [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration#createExpressionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html#createExpressionHandler()) so that set your own [`ParameterNameDiscoverer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterNameDiscoverer.html) in custom [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler result = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    result.setApplicationContext(this.context);
    result.setParameterNameDiscoverer(new AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer(PathVariable.class.getName()));
    return result;
  }

}
```

In the [sample project](https://github.com/sandarkin/so-q37435824) you can see result in console output something like this

```
2016-06-06 17:09:01.635  INFO 2871 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.s.so.q37435824.SecurityService: myParam value from PathVariable equals 1
```

Best regards

Comment: This is a similar solution to the vzamanillo's answer, just without a custom ParameterNameDiscoverer. In fact, I have already implemented almost identical one. However, I don't set applicationContext on the expression handler. Is it needed here?

Comment: @pkalinow, yes, it is necessary to set applicationContext, otherwise you will get the `No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'securityService'` SpelEvaluationException during the evaluation of SpEL expression

Comment: I don't get such an error. Maybe because I use also another `@Configuration` class for web security - extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Answer (score 2):

Following configuration was not tested, but based on research of [sources of spring security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security), so try to change your Spring Security configuration xml as follows

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="parameterNameDiscoverer" ref="parameterNameDiscoverer"/>
</bean>

<bean id="parameterNameDiscoverer" class="org.springframework.security.core.parameters.AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works and I have used it in my configuration, with some changes:
1. Constructor parameter should be a list (already edited your answer).
2. These beans should be defined in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, or wherever the REST controllers are defined.

Answer (score 0):

From Spring security official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-path-variables) the requested usecase can be achieved . But to use you need to upgrade to spring 4.1.0, I didn't tried by looks like this is achievable

Comment: I knew about this method, but it is not exactly what I needed. I want to use method annotations on controllers, not URI patterns.